# CRecordset::GetFieldValue() throws exception (but not always)

Tags: database, mfc

Can someone explain this strange behaviour?

```cpp
CString A, B;
CRecordset  rs.Open( forwardOnly, "select A,B from table", readOnly);

// does not work:
rs.GetFieldValue( "A", A); // ok
rs.GetFieldValue( "B", B); // throws; m_nRetCode is set to -1; 
//trace says "dbcore.cpp(174) : AppMsg - invalid descriptor index."

// works:
rs.GetFieldValue( (short) 0, A); // ok
rs.GetFieldValue( (short) 1, B); // ok

// does´nt work either !?
rs.GetFieldValue( rs.GetFieldIndexByName( "A"), A); // ok
rs.GetFieldValue( rs.GetFieldIndexByName( "B"), B); // asserts !?

// throws a different exception:
rs.GetFieldValue( "A", A); // ok
rs.GetFieldValue( "A", A); // throws, but m_nRetCode is 100 now and the trace is saying "data allready fetched" !?

// strange...
rs.GetFieldValue( (short) 0, A); // ok
rs.GetFieldValue( "B", B); // this works
rs.GetFieldValue( "A", A); // this asserts ???
```

I searched around an got one hint, saying *forwardOnly* isn´t the correct cursor, but using *snapshot* doesn´t change a thing. Can anyone explain?

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Think I found the answer: it seems to lie beyond CRecordset in *SQLGetData()*:

> If the driver does not support extensions to SQLGetData, the function
>   can return data only for unbound columns **with a number greater than
>   that of the last bound column**. Furthermore, within a row of data, the
>   value of the Col_or_Param_Num argument in each call to SQLGetData must
>   be greater than or equal to the value of Col_or_Param_Num in the
>   previous call; that is, data must be retrieved in increasing column
>   number order.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlgetdata-function?view=sql-server-2017